# Triangles with side length a, b and c and $a^n$, $b^n$ and $c^n$

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, geometry

For which triangles with side length a, b and c do exist triangles with side length $a^n$, $b^n$ and $c^n$ for all positive integers $n\geq2$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is

> all isosceles triangles with sides a=b>=c.

All other triangles have

> a longest side that will as the exponent n increases eventually exceed the sum of the two other sides.